# Is a divides infinitely many repunits?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: i dont know whl]
Let (a,10)=1
Let n=9k{phi(a)}   using eulerphi function

k is positive integer.

When (a,9)= 1 , 3 it is okay

Because  81 and a divides 10^n-1 by

Binomial theorem and CRT

So a divides (10^n-1)/9

But I don t know when (a,n)=9,
Must a divides (10^n-1)/9 ? I dont think so

Then how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ and $10$ be relatively prime. If $9a$ divides $10^n-1$, then $a$ will divide $\frac{10^n-1}{9}$.

So let $n=k\varphi(9a)$.